# How to de-serialize modx_session table data?

Tags: php, serialization, modx-revolution

Modx stores it's session data in the database, serialized [in some format] in the modx_session.data table.column. It looks like this:

> modx.user.0.resourceGroups|a:1:{s:3:"web";a:8:{i:0;s:2:"10";i:1;s:2:"12";i:2;s:2:"13";i:3;s:2:"14";i:4;s:1:"3";i:5;s:1:"7";i:6;s:1:"8";i:7;s:1:"9";}}modx.user.0.attributes|a:1:{s:3:"web";a:4:{s:16:"modAccessContext";a:1:{s:3:"web";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}}s:22:"modAccessResourceGroup";a:8:{i:10;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:12;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:13;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:14;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:3;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:7;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:8;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:9;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}}s:17:"modAccessCategory";a:0:{}s:28:"sources.modAccessMediaSource";a:0:{}}}modx.user.contextTokens|a:0:{}this_anonymous_pagecount|i:2;

That is a session record for an anonymous user.

What format is it in and how do I unserialize it?

the normal php unserialize($modx_session['data']) returns false.

Answer (score 2):

Since MODX modSession extends as a xPDOObject, So its probably best idea to read it through some xPDO/MODX objects code.

> **UPDATE:** Thanks to [@jason-coward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4484445/jason-coward) The way to decode session data, or using it in your MDOX snippets etc is bekow:
>
> ```
> modSession->get(‘data’)
> ```

But if we go vanilla php route, I got the data *decoded* via php's `session_decode` function.

Quick php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$input = 'modx.user.0.resourceGroups|a:1:{s:3:"web";a:8:{i:0;s:2:"10";i:1;s:2:"12";i:2;s:2:"13";i:3;s:2:"14";i:4;s:1:"3";i:5;s:1:"7";i:6;s:1:"8";i:7;s:1:"9";}}modx.user.0.attributes|a:1:{s:3:"web";a:4:{s:16:"modAccessContext";a:1:{s:3:"web";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}}s:22:"modAccessResourceGroup";a:8:{i:10;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:12;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:13;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:14;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:3;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:7;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:8;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}i:9;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"principal";i:0;s:9:"authority";s:1:"0";s:6:"policy";a:1:{s:4:"load";b:1;}}}}s:17:"modAccessCategory";a:0:{}s:28:"sources.modAccessMediaSource";a:0:{}}}modx.user.contextTokens|a:0:{}this_anonymous_pagecount|i:2;';
$output = session_decode($input);
$ses = $_SESSION;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ses);
?>
```

Here is the decoded data:

```
Array
(
    [modx.user.0.resourceGroups] => Array
    (
        [web] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 14
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 7
            [6] => 8
            [7] => 9
            )

        )

    [modx.user.0.attributes] => Array
    (
        [web] => Array
        (
            [modAccessContext] => Array
            (
                [web] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                )

            [modAccessResourceGroup] => Array
            (
                [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                [13] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                [14] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0
                        [authority] => 0
                        [policy] => Array
                        (
                            [load] => 1
                            )

                        )

                    )

                )

[modAccessCategory] => Array
(
    )

[sources.modAccessMediaSource] => Array
(
    )

)

)

[modx.user.contextTokens] => Array
(
    )

[this_anonymous_pagecount] => 2
)
```

**Related information:**

modSession Class https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/master/core/model/modx/modsessionhandler.class.php#L170

modSession API Docs http://api.modx.com/revolution/2.2/db_core_model_modx_modsession.class.html#%5CmodSession